# Kafka MySQL as Consumer

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

I have Kafka as message broker in server ecosystem,
can I somehow make MySQL as consumer?

I need to write data directly in database coming from Kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly AFAIK.  Kafka does not provide facilities to mirror its data to different datastores. You'll something else to pull the messages out of Kafka and write their contents to SQL.

A common pattern is use Storm to pull the data out of Kafka, then to write it to a datastore, in this case MySQL.

Comment: thanks... and can i prioritize messages using storm? Because Kafka doesn't support message prioritization.

Comment: Yes. Storm is java linked to a paralleling engine. So if you can prioritize it using java, you can prioritize it using Storm (some caveats apply).

Comment: can you please share some example or link i can refer from.

Comment: The storm starter examples are probably the best place to begin:
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

Answer (score 1):

MySql can't be a direct consumer for Kafka. I would suggest you to use available Consumer API to create Kafka client which will be able consume messages from Kafka clusters and then messages can be stored in database.